# Azure Table Storage API returns 0 results with Continuation Token

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are using .net Azure storage client library to retrieve data from server. But when we try to retrieve data, the result have only 0 items with a continuation token. When we fetch the next page with this continuation token we again gets the same result. However when we use the 4th continuation token fetched like this, we are getting the proper result with 15 items.( The items count for all requests are 15). This issue is observed only when we tried applying filter conditions. The code used to fetch result is given below

```
    var tableReference = _tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
                var query = new TableQuery();
                query.Where("'DeviceId' eq '99'"); // DeviceId is of type Int32
                query.TakeCount = 15;

    var resultsQuery = tableReference.ExecuteQuerySegmented(query, token);
                var nextToken = resultsQuery.ContinuationToken;
                var results = resultsQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. From [`Query Timeout and Pagination`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx):

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 items
>   at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the
>   result set contains more than 1,000 items, if the query did not
>   complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
>   boundary, the response includes headers which provide the developer
>   with continuation tokens to use in order to resume the query at the
>   next item in the result set. Continuation token headers may be
>   returned for a Query Tables operation or a Query Entities operation.

I noticed that you're not using `PartitionKey` in your query. This will result in full table scan. Recommendation would be to always use `PartitionKey` (and possibly `RowKey`) in your queries to avoid full table scans. I would highly recommend reading [`Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) to get the most out of Azure Tables.

**UPDATE: Explaining "If the query crosses the partition boundary"**

Let me try with an example as to what I understand by Partition Bounday. Let's assume you have 1 million rows in your table evenly spread across 10 Partitions (let's assume your PartitionKeys are 001, 002, 003,...010). Now we know that the data in Azure Tables is organized by PartitionKey and then in a Partition by RowKey. Since in your query you did not specify PartitionKey, Table Service starts from 1st Partition (i.e. PartitionKey == 001) and tries to find the matching data there. If it does not find any data in that Partition, it does not know whether the data is there in another Partition so instead of going to the next Partition, it simply returns back with a continuation token and leave it to the client consuming the API to decide whether they want to continue the search using the same parameters + continuation token or revise their search to start again.